# textfile update, add and delete

Tags: php, html

Ok i have this code:

```
<?php

//this is the thispage.php

$file = "data.txt";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$url = $_POST['url'];

$data = file('data.txt');
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $line) {
$line = explode('|', $line);
$i++;
}

if (isset($_POST['submits'])) {
$fp = fopen($file, "a+");
fwrite($fp, $i."|".$name."|".$url."|\n");
fclose($fp);
}


?>
```

and this index.php.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<form name="form1" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="url">
<input type="submit" name="submits" value="ADD"><br>
</form>
<form name="form2" action="thispage.php" method="POST">
<?php

$display = file("data.txt");
   for ($i=0; $i<=count($display)-1; $i++) {
   $lines = explode("|",$display[$i]);

   print('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$lines[0].'">
             <input type="text" name="name" value="'.$lines[1].'">
             <input type="text" name="url" value="'.$lines[2].'">
             <input type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE">
             <input type="submit" name="delete" value="DELETE"><br>');
   }

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the data.txt contains.

```
1|John|http://www.john.com|
2|Mark|http://www.mark.com|
3|Fred|http://www.fred.com|
4|Johnxxx|asdasdasdasd|
```

Im having a hard time, making this one works, trying to update and delete, I can add but I cant update and delete either. hope you guys can help me, this is a expirement. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use database instead? you can easily, update, delete, insert using database.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, im rerouting everything right now using database as backend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking for here, normally you would use a database for this kind of storing as  ulvund said, but as you say it's an experiment so I go with it ;)

Based on the code you have provided, which is insert and view I see a few problems that may occur. You are having problems with update and delete you say, but there is no code for that parts. You have some code that don't work right, or are you asking for what to do next?

**Problems I see with this code**

- What if someone submits a form with a "\n" (new-line character)? That will mess up your data (Or at least several lines, depending on how many \n the users posts.
- What happens when you delete line #2, and you go to insert a new line again? You will end up with 2 line #4 because of the way you count number of lines and used the results of that to make up the id for the next INSERT
- $line = explode('|', $line);
  This line in "thispage.php" does nothing at all, because you only want to count the number of line, not extract all the data into an array. And as I said before this way of making up the id is not a good idea.

So, if this experiment is worth the work for you, you need to consider storing the "Auto increase ID" either in a separate file, or make the first line of the database file a meta-line, containing meta data as A.I. ID and other stuff you might want to have there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have, something like the below might work. However, be sure to read the answers from [user1362861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363652/482758) and [ulvund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363443/482758). There are many ways in which this could go wrong, and if you plan on applying this in practice you're better off with a database.

```
<?php
//this is the thispage.php

$file = "data.txt";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$url  = $_POST['url'];
$id   = $_POST['id'];
$mode = $_POST['mode'];

$data = file('data.txt');
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $line) {
    // You're not doing anything with this.
    //$line = explode('|', $line);
    $i++;
}

if (isset($_POST['submits'])) {
    if ($mode === 'add') {
        $fp = fopen($file, "a+");
        fwrite($fp, $i."|".$name."|".$url."|\n");
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $fp = fopen($file, "r+");
        foreach ($data as $line) {
            $l = explode('|', $line); // $l = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '|'));
            if ($id === $l[0]) {
                if ($mode === 'update') {
                    fwrite($fp, $l[0]."|".$name."|".$url."|\n");
                } // else delete; don't re-write this line.
            } else {
                fwrite($fp, $line);
                // This assumes IDs are attached to data, not line numbers.
                // If that isn't the case, storing the ID (line number) is pointless.
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
?>
```